# Anchor text in Short code →

Tags: shortcode

I have a short code in wordpress, below is a part of the shortcode →

[tm_single_image animation="fadeInLeft" classname="sub-banner1" image="http://trafficspinners.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/wedding-seating-chart-downloadable2.jpg"]

I want to put a clickable anchor text in this image, Please guide me.

Widget Definition →

```
/*=============Sub Banner ============ */
function shortcode_subbanner($atts, $content = null)
{
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'image' => '',
            'padding' => '',
            'margin' => '',
            'height' => '',
            'width' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'link_url' => ''    

        ), $atts));

        $variables  = '';
        $output = '';

        if(!empty($image)) :
            $variables .= 'padding:'.$padding.';';
            $variables .= 'margin:'.$margin.';';
        endif;

        $output .= '<div class="sub-container '.$class.'" style="'.$variables.'">';
        $output .= '<div class="inner-image"><a href="'.$link_url.'" target="_Blank"><img src='.$image.' height="'.$height.'" width="'.$width.'"></a></div>'; 
        $output .= '</div>';
        return $output;
}
add_shortcode('subbanner', 'shortcode_subbanner');
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code for the shortcode defintion, thanks.

Comment: Done sir, Please check.

Comment: You've posted the definition of the `[subbanner]` shortcode, not `[tm_single_image]` that you first posted.  Note that the subbanner shortcode code snippet is missing attribute escaping and is using `extract` that's no longer recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add link_url to the shortcode, like so?

[tm_single_image animation="fadeInLeft" classname="sub-banner1" image="http://trafficspinners.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/wedding-seating-chart-downloadable2.jpg" link_url="YOUR-LINK-HERE"]

Unless I am not understanding what you mean by 'clickable anchor text'.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Michelle. In the code you can see the options available in the widget:

```
'image' => '',
'padding' => '',
'margin' => '',
'height' => '',
'width' => '',
'class' => '',
'link_url' => '
```

Adding "link_url" to your widget will add an anchor to the image.